# Speech dereverbaration via maximum kurtosis adaptive filtering

Tags: noise, speech-processing, adaptive-filters

I'm trying to code the algorithm described in [Speech dereverbaration via maximum-kurtosis subband adaptive filtering](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ICASSP01makurt.pdf) by *Gillespie, Malvar and Florencio*, and the signal looks cleaner in when I plot it.
However there are 2 aspects of the results that are worrying me:

1. The sound level seems lower than the original when played.
2. And the sound comes out muffled.

I'm quite new to speech signal processing so I was wondering whether the latter issues occur commonly or is it just my bad coding?

Here is the part of the code that corresponds to the adaptive filter. I believe it should be the problematic part.

---

```
for n=1:500
 %Sig is the sum of the product of the FFT of the kusrtosis gradient and
 %the complex conjugate of the FFT of the LP residual of the reverberant
 %signal
    sig=0;
    ii=1;

    while ii<length(F)-L
        sig=sig+sum(F(ii:ii+L).*Yconj(ii:ii+L));
        ii=ii+L;
    end
 %H is the frequency domain representation of the filter and the following are the update equations

%Hpr is G' in the paper 
    Hpr(n+1)=H(n)+(mu/M)*sig;

    if Hpr(n)==0 || isnan(Hpr(n))==1
       H(n+1)=0;
    else

        H(n+1)=Hpr(n)/abs(Hpr(n));
    end
 %getting the optimized signal
    Zt=Yleftres.*H;

    zt=ifft(Zt);
%updating the value of the kurosis gradient
    q=1:length(zt);
    while q<length(zt);

        secmoment=beta*secmoment+(1-beta)*zt(q:q+881).^2;
        fourthmoment=beta*fourthmoment+(1-beta)*zt(q:q+881).^4;

        f(q:q+881)=4*(secmoment*(zt(q:q+881).^3)-fourthmoment*zt(q:q+881))/(secmoment.^3);
        q=q+881;

        cleaner=isNaN(f(q:q+881));
        cleaner=cleaner-1;
        cleaner=abs(cleaner);
        f(q:q+881)=cleaner.*f(q:q+881);

    end
    F=fft(f);

   %   Hpr(n+1)=H(n)+(mu/M)*sig;
end
```

[image]

Comment: While interesting, I am afraid that the question appears to be too broad or unclear. It is hard to comment on details of the code without the code and if the code runs too long, it is hard to go over it line by line and compare to the paper. Perhaps you have done some preliminary "debugging" yourself and you would require some help with a particular part? I think that would be a more efficient question in terms of getting help.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. I have done some debugging of my own but since I'm not very familiar with adaptive filters I can't seem to pinpoint the source of the mentioned issue. I will post the part of the code corresponding to the filter because I think that is where the problem is.
Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: I just tried to run my code for more iterations and the result was very good. I guess it was a question of fine tuning the parameters to get the result I wanted. Anyway, thank you very much for helping out.

Comment: No worries. Would you be interested in providing a "self-answer" to this post? I am asking for 2 reasons: 1) This is an interesting topic and I am guessing that regulars to DSP.SE would appreciate a little bit more information about the technique and how it works from someone with already some experience on it and 2) It would help in closing the question gracefully. You can simply then "accept" your own answer and this will stop the question from circulating on the board as one that is still looking for an answer. All the best.

Comment: It seems like a good idea  for people who might be interested to try it out. I'll do it now and close the question.
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @EliasC It would be great if you could share your full code.

Comment: Hey @RoG I posted a link for the code below, it's been a while now but still I hope it helps.

Comment: @EliasC Thanks for the full code link. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @EliasC Unfortunately it doesn't seem to recover simple filters (e.g. [1 0 0 0 0 0.5]) that I apply to a test audio clip. I wonder what the filter produced by your rir() function looks like? Or could you post the code for rir() also?

Comment: @RoG I added the rir filter I used in the edited post below hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was advised to me  by A_A in the comment section I will close this thread with a "self-answer".
The code present in the question is a code for a speech signal de-reverberation adaptive filter based on the Kurtosis signal of the signal's Lp residual. The original idea isn't mine (the reference is in the question). But the problem I faced was mainly due to the fact that my sensor did not convert to the desired result. I drastically increased the number of iterations the adaptive filter does and the result converged.(from n=500 to n=2000) There are others parameters that can be tweaked too (like mu) but I haven't had the time recently to thoroughly evaluate their effects.

Here's a link to download the code hope it helps. (expires by April 18th)

[Code download link](https://mysnu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/chemalielias_seoul_ac_kr/EQf85jBkW3JMhkcbTgIBQBEBzzteflcaQ0yCfkDNL8VRZA?e=UZn2XU)

Here's the link for the RIR code I used, I did not write the code though. I downloaded the file from matlab file exchange. The original author is Stephen G. McGovern, he also wrote a paper with the theoretical explanations for the RIR filter.

[RIR code](https://mysnu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/chemalielias_seoul_ac_kr/ETERzOu0BepOv40rKYu1vLABVIEU_j-BTCX1ecu0ZQyOsA?e=NUl4SL)

Comment: The link to the code is expired. Can you please upload a new link? Thank you

Comment: Yes, I found it expired as well. Perhaps you could post it on File Exchange.

Comment: [Code Download Link](https://mysnu-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/chemalielias_seoul_ac_kr/EvOImPOLRr9EiEoURwAz4B4Biyz590UeKqPUkFgB-a4M1A?e=TYMmp8)

This links to a folder containing all the code files, this link does not have an expiry date, please keep me posted if you have any difficulties and I apologize for the delay.